Creating classes in C
is this how you guys would create a "class" in C?  How about an interface?  I'm guessing we just use function pointers for everything and we can change where the function pointers point to?
#ifndef CLASS
#define CLASS

void method1() { printf("method #1"); }
void method2() { printf("method #2"); }

typedef struct {
    void (*method1)(void);
    void (*method2)(void);
} Class;

Class class;

void class_setup()
{
    class.method1 = &method1;
    class.method2 = &method2;
}

#endif

int main()
{
    class_setup();

    class.method1();
    class.method2();

    return 0;
}


Normally a class would have some data as well as methods, and the methods would need to access the data.  Think about how you would manage that.  If you have questions about that approach, please try to ask them in a way that isn't opinion-based as your current question is.

void method1() and void (*method1)(void) although is compatible, but is not the same functions.

How would one write object-oriented code in C?, C as an object oriented language

If you want classes, there are languages where this is built in. :-)

Actually, there are two ways to do OOP in C. And while function pointers do play a huge role in them, we do not put them inside the "class" structures that much - primarily because we do not have this in C.
class as a set of functions in the open
It is a most common and, while not exactly pretty, still usable approach. Just have a bunch of functions to do something with an object. For example, please take a look at Glib and GTK+. These two libraries are de-facto the most used and usable object oriented libraries in C. In case of GTK+, to work with "sibling" classes you use "sibling" functions:
void gtk_window_set_child (GtkWindow* window, GtkWidget* child);
void gtk_button_set_child (GtkButton* button, GtkWidget* child);

As you can see, you need to pass a pointer to object (this) as a first parameter and distinction to which class this method belongs to is done by function names.
At the same time, both classes (GtkWindow and GtkButton) are children of GtkWidget and can be passed directly to gtk_widget_*() functions with a manual type conversion:
GtkButton *button = gtk_button_new();
gtk_widget_set_size_request((GtkWidget*)button, 100, 100);

Actually, early C++ compilers were just preprocessors which made a C code using same approach. A method cls::foo() becomes a function cls_foo(cls *this). And even now, if you compile C++ code into a shared library, you will see inside just a bunch of functions with names like this. Read about "name mangling" and how it is done by different compilers.
class as a set of functions in a hidden hash table
This approach to do OOP, is much less used. In commercial product it was implemented in Photon - GUI library for old QNX (newer version of OS switched to C++ for GUI). As example of open source project: IUP
It uses a different approach to methods - a hash array of function pointers. When you creating a new class, you need to register its unique type in the list of classes and register all methods. Also there is no parent-child data types, only a base data type with a class identifier inside an object. Not very easy inside, but this allows a more convenient way for practical application:
PtWidget_t *window = PtCreateWidget( PtWindow, Pt_NO_PARENT, 0, NULL);
PtArg_t const btn_args[] = {...};
PtWidget_t *button = PtCreateWidget( PtButton, window, btn_arg_cnt, btn_args);
// Here PtWindow and PtButton are references to registered classes

// and both widgets can be passed to a single function
PtSetResource (window, Pt_ARG_TEXT_STRING, "Window title", 0);
PtSetResource (button, Pt_ARG_TEXT_STRING, "Click Me!", 0);

And behind the scene the PtSetResource() function will use a two dimensional hash table of function pointers keyed on class references (PtWindow or PtButton read from inside an object) and on method selector (Pt_ARG_TEXT_STRING) passed directly to the function.

The answer seems to be fully generated by AI.

i see, thank you :)

"primarily because we do not have this in C” is kind misleading. What you actually mean is that this is implicitly generated by the C++ compiler whereas in C you have to explicitly pass it (see your GTK window and button functions). The reason is that when you call a function, whether is is embedded in the structure or an explicit function, unlike C++, the data doesn’t go along for the ride. You have to tell C explicitly where the data is. See OP source code. Even though method1() is called, there is no pointer to the structure and that is the problem C++ fixes.

For creating a "class" in C, you can use function pointers, which look something like this:
typedef void (*classMethod)(void);
Note that the type here is "classMethod", and that the function name does not have to match. So to use this it would look like
typedef void (*classMethod)(void);

typedef struct {
    classMethod method1;
    classMethod method2;
} Class;

Now that you have the methods correct, you'd need to set them up in your class_setup function. In c, the function name can effectively be treated as the address of that function, so there's no need to use & here. It can just be class.method1 = method1 (However you can still say &method1, the compiler works with it if that's more clear to you)
In the case that you need to use an equivalent to "self" or "this", you'll need to pass the address of the variable, as C does not have any built-in way to do this. It can be done with a similar function pointer typedef void (*classMethodSelf)(Class *);. This would be defined as

typedef struct Class Class;
typedef void (*classMethod)(void);
typedef void (*classMethodSelf)(Class *);

struct Class{
    classMethod method1;
    classMethod method2;
    classMethodSelf method3;
};

You'll see that the typedef for class has been moved, this is because the type needs to be declared before it's defined, in order to pass Class as a type to the function pointer.
Another important thing to note if you are unfamiliar with pointers to structs, is that it's members will be accessed with variable->member, and not variable.member.
Note that further arguments are just declared in the function pointer like a normal function declaration, but without the variable names.
If you'd like to have a return value to the method, it's just changing the first type in the typedef. Then you can use it like a normal function.

int return5(void){
    return 5;
}

typedef struct Class Class;
typedef void (*classMethod)(void);
typedef void (*classMethodSelf)(Class *);
typedef int (*classMethodInt)(void);

struct Class{
    classMethod method1;
    classMethod method2;
    classMethodSelf method3;
    classMethodInt methodInt;
};

// (inside main function)
Class class;
class.methodInt = return5;
int x = class.methodInt();
printf("%i\n", x); // 5

If you have any questions or need clarification please ask, Good day.

best method: add two plusses to your language name

While I agree that that would be the best method, I'm not about to tell the poster not to do this, because it can be fun and educational to try and figure this out on your own.

Now, make the data opaque to other functions. It’s not just about calling functions, that is the easy part. OOP is assuring that the data is only manipulated by the object; that the user can’t just reach in and twiddle data without going through the approved functions.

No. In C we don't do that. C doesn't have classes nor methods.
We have functions to do something
void function_a() { printf("a"); }
void function_b() { printf("b"); }

We have structures to store some data
typedef struct {
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
} point_2d_t;

And we process the data using functions
// by value
void print_point_2d(point_2d_t value) {
    printf("(%i, %i)", value.x, value.y);
}

// by pointer
void assign_value_to_point_2d(point_2d_t *ptr, int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    ptr->x = x;
    ptr->y = y;
}
void scale_point_2d(point_2d_t *ptr, float scale) {
    ptr->x = (int32_t)(ptr->x * scale);
    ptr->y = (int32_t)(ptr->y * scale);
    // or this way for short
    ptr->x *= scale;
    ptr->y *= scale;
}

Also we can use pointers to a function to provide some callback
void for_each_point_2d_do(point_2d_t *arr, size_t size, void (*f)(point_2d_t)) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        f(arr[i]);
}


that's not true. Originally C++ code were transformed into C then compile by a C compiler. That's a common technique used in complex programs. Linux kernel drivers also use OOP in C a lot: Object oriented programming in C, How would one write object-oriented code in C?, Object Oriented pattern in C?, How do you do inheritance in a non-OO language?

@phuclv Probably projects on my job are not complex enough. :-)

@phuclv - The Linux kernel is special, as C++ is specifically banned. So they have to fake it. Ordinary code doesn't.

@BoP yes, but it's also used in GTK or other places where C is strictly required

@phuclv Well, the sentence "In C we don't do that." is to general but still it's correct that in most C projects/programs "we don't do that". And even when we (for some reason) are forced to use C, we will in most cases write the code as traditional "C code" without trying to apply a concept that C wasn't designed for.
